# Representation of $\pi$ using algebra and exp/log.

Tags: number-theory, pi, approximation-theory

Can $\pi$ be represented exactly using a mixture of algebraic as well as exp/log functions, all real valued?

I know it can't be done using only algebra since its transcendental, but what if we introduced exp/log functions? Is there any theory about its possibility?

Comment: How about $\ln(-1)/(-1)^{1/2}$?

Comment: The original question involves only real valued functions and your example, though ingenious, does not fit this as it involves complex numbers.

Comment: It is easy to derive from http://mathworld.wolfram.com/RamanujanConstant.html (still just good **approximation**): $$\pi \approx \dfrac{\log(640320^3+744)}{\sqrt{163}};$$ but to get exact formula: many doubts...

Comment: Maybe of interest https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Approximations_of_%CF%80

Comment: If you want a finite expression then it appears to be difficult. $\pi$ is linked with circular functions and circular functions have no link with log/exp unless one goes in the complex domain.

Answer (score 2):

The short answer is "NO" unless you allow such inverse trigonometric expressions as $4\arctan(1)$ and similar.  However, there are exceedingly good approximations using Heegner numbers (there are only nine: 1, 2, 3, 7, 11, 19, 43, 76, 163), the last of which produces: $$\frac{\ln(640320^3+744)} {\sqrt{163}}$$ which gives $\pi|$ to more than 30 decimal places and an error of $2.237\times 10^{-31}$

Even better approximations to more than 50 decimal places are also possible.  Then there are the infinite series that can be generated from the series for expressions such as $$\frac{\pi}4=4 \arctan\frac1 5-\arctan\frac1 {239}$$ etc, which provide a means to calculate $\pi$ to any desired accuracy.

Comment: @Dave L. Renfro, Dr Peter McGowan: use $\;\ldots +744\;\;$ instead of $\;\ldots -744\;\;$ to get mentioned approximation.

Comment: Can you point to a reference for a proof that the short answer is No?  In light of Lord Shark the Unknown's comment regarding $\ln(-1)/(-1)^{1/2}$, there must be some subtlety in the proof utilizing the requirement that everything stay real valued.